# Is im(A) a subspace if det(A) is not zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

It's a true/false question. But, what I'm concerned about is you can't take the determinant of a n x n matrix, so how would you even go about to answering this question? I think its true just because of the fact that determinants cannot be taken for m x n matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: The image of the linear map associated to a matrix is *always* a subspace. And the determinant is defined only for square matrices.

Comment: The title is misleading because it isn't $A$ but "image" of $A$ that you are concerned about being a subspace.  Yet I agree with you that taking a determinant won't make sense unless $A$ is square.

Comment: Hint: Think about the conditions so that the system $Ax=b$ has only one solution